# javascript object gets overridden in IE

Tags: javascript

Geeks,

I have the following codes:

Snippet A:

```
var x = (function(){ this.id="Dog"; return this; }());
var y = (function(){ this.id="Cat"; return this; }());
alert(x.id); //outputs Cat
alert(y.id); //outputs Cat
```

Snippet B:

```
var x = (new function(){ this.id="Dog"; });
var y = (new function(){ this.id="Cat"; });
alert(x.id); //ouputs Dog
alert(y.id); //outputs Cat
```

Why is x replaced by y in Snippet A and not on B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the snippet A, on x and y, the `this` keyword refers to the global object, you are creating setting the value to the same global variable (`window.id`).

In the snippet B, you are using the `new` operator, and the functions are executed as constructor functions, the `this` keyword refers to a newly created object.

To avoid that behavior in your snippet A, you can create a new object instance and use it instead of `this`:

```
var x = (function(){
  var instance = {};
  instance.id = "Dog"; 
  return instance;
}());

var y = (function(){ 
  var instance = {};
  instance.id = "Cat"; 
  return instance;
}());

alert(x.id); //outputs Dog
alert(y.id); //outputs Cat
```

When you call global functions, since they are members of the global object:

```
globalFunction();
```

Is equivalent to:

```
window.globalFunction();
```

And the context inside that function will be the global object itself (`window`).

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two is that Snippet B is using a **[constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function)** by prefixing the call with the `new` keyword, while snippet A is not. This is the short answer.

The long answer is that although snippet A introduces a new scope on each anonymous function invocation, since it is *not* being used in a constructor context it's `this` variable simply points to the global `window` object. So snippet A is equivalent to this:

```
var x = (function(){ window.id="Dog"; return window; }());
var y = (function(){ window.id="Cat"; return window; }());
```

Thus, each invocation just clobbers the same [global] variable.

Since snippet B is using the `new` keyword, you define and immediately call a constructor function. JavaScript proceeds to initialize the `this` variable inside the constructor function to point to a new instance of the [just defined] anonymous function.

You may have seen the `new function(){}` idiom some time ago being touted as the best way to define and immediately execute a block of code. Well, it comes with the overhead of JavaScript object instantiation (as you've found), and is not generally used as widely anymore.